Estimating the root of the equation $^+^=^x$ for triangle with sides $,,$
Let $(,,)$ be the sides of a triangle of circumradius $$. By the roots of a triangle we mean the positive root of the exponential equation $^+^=^x$. Clearly for the root to exist, we must have $≤<$. Such transcendental equation, typically do not have an elementary closed-form solution so estimating the root gets complicated. We can get a trivial upper bound for x as follows.
$$
a^x + b^x \ge 2b^x \ge c^x \implies x \le \dfrac{\log 2}{\log c - \log b} \tag 1
$$

For a triangle with sides $(1.355016, 1.364955, 1.994336)$, using $(1)$ we get $x \le 1.8279721$ which is very close to the actual root of about $1.81058$
But for the triangle with sides $(1.287221, 1.681008, 1.983988)$, using $(1)$ we get $x \le 4.182762$ which is not very close to the actual root of about $2.499521$

So I wanted to find a better estimate of the root. I observed using experimental data that
$$
x \le \dfrac{R^3}{\{(a+b-c)(c-b)\}^{3/2}} - \dfrac{8(b-a)}{R} \tag 2
$$
This estimate is interesting because it gives the upper bound in terms of a well know quantity related to the triangle; the deficit of the triangle inequality $+−$ and $R$ rather than a brute force algebraic manipulations?

For the same triangle with sides $(1.355016, 1.364955, 1.994336)$, using $(2)$ we get $x \le 3.160539$ which is worse than the estimate using $(1)$
But for the other triangle with sides $(1.287221, 1.681008, 1.983988)$, using $(2)$ we get $x \le 2.990535$ which is much better than the estimate using $(1)$

In all the above triangles, the circumradius was $R= 1$. Simulations for billions of triangles show that $(2)$ holds and also that sometimes $(1)$ gives the better estimate and sometimes $(2)$ is better. Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have
$$
x \le \min\left\{\dfrac{\log 2}{\log c - \log a}, 
\dfrac{R^3}{\{(a+b-c)(c-b)\}^{3/2}} - \dfrac{8(b-a)}{R}\right\} \tag 3
$$
Question 1: Can $(2)$ be proved?
Question 2: Is there a simpler criteria (rather brute form algebraic manipulations) to determine when is $(2)$ a better estimate than $(1)$ for example something in terms of parameters of the triangle.
